# which way is better for put file to amazon s3 from server?

Tags: node.js, express, restify, fs, knox-amazon-s3-client

I want provide a rest service api by restify ( or express )

- the duty of service is let client who could put audio/mpeg or other
  binary file to our server, and then verify the authentication, if
  pass, put the file to amazon s3, and then check the s3 client
  response statusCode, if s3 client reponse statusCode == 200 , do
  somethings

> **solution1**: using request stream pipe to put files to
>   amazon by knox

```
var stream = s3.put(filepath, {options});
serverReq.pipe(stream);
stream.on('response', function(err, s3Res) {
    if (err) { console.log(err); }
    if (s3Res.statusCode == 200) { store file infos on DB}
}
```

> **solution2**: using formdiable and fs to pre store file on server local temp folder and then put files to amazon by knox

```
(after pre store file on server local temp folder)
s3.putFile(sourcePath, destPath, {options}, function(err, _res) {
    (clear local files from local temp folder)

    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (_res.statusCode == 200) {console.log('save on %s', s3.url(dest))}
    res.send(_res.statusCode);
    return next();
});
```

> **which way is better between solution 1 and solution 2 or other better way ?? 
>   and does here has any performance issues need to know?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the server load and your available bandwidth, your diskio is your biggest potential bottleneck. I would say go with solution 1 that streams the file directly and doesn't store it to physical media.  Make sure you don't attempt to store the entire object to memory either or you could run into a system resources problem.

Comment: is there has any methods to limit incoming buffer size ?

Comment: You can manage the buffers sizes and bandwidth by using response.pause() and response.resume().  This will cause the TCP algorithms to back off appropriately.  (see http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_pause )